# What is the point of assigning assassins to cities?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

What is the point of assigning assassins to cities in AC Revelations?

Does the experience income from those cities level up the assassins I assign there? For example, if I place a level 2 assassin in a captured city does the experience income from that city help that assassin level up? Will he reach level 3 and so on? What's the point of building an assassin den in a city?

Comment: Please refrain from asking multiple questions in a single post, even if they are related. You are more than welcome to [ask another question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your assassins into the Master Assassin rankings, you have to put them in one of your dens in Instanbul (you go around and free the dens, then put level 10 assassins in them. Should have a black diamond on it for 'Master Assassin Mission' ).

As for assigning Assassins to cities... eh... don't bother. They increase the maximum Assassin control for the city, and the assigned assassins get XP every time the income from that city comes in. That's about it.

Comment: I removed the portion about Master Assassin rankings, it should be asked in another question. I assumed the first question that he asked was more important so I kept that part. Feel free to look for Sreyan's new question activity and answer him again there.

Comment: @Phill.Zitt: So I guess not all my assassins can become master assassins right ? Do the experience generated from the cities help  the assigned assassins become master assassins ?

Comment: @Sreyan However many dens there are in Constantioppli is how many Master Assassins you can have. IIRC, it's 7. To actually have an Assassin become a Master Assassin, you have to assign them to a den and do the Master Assassin Mission associated with it - it's not about how much experience they have (though they must be level 10). The XP gained from assignments is the same as any other kind of XP, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Phill.Zitt: No unless you can assign all your assassins in Constantioppli, they cant become master assassins. Thanks for helping out.